# How to change mechanism of listener like launchedeffect with compose function within?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, observer-pattern

I need to change `swipeStates` when `list` param is changed, but `rememberSwipeableCardState` is `composable function` so I cannot do it I receive an error:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

```
    LaunchedEffect(list) {
        if (list != null) {
            swipeStates = list.map { it to rememberSwipeableCardState() }
        }
    }
```

How to create such workaround for this mechanism?

Comment: You can use custom implementation and integrate custom Saver function for rememberSwipeableCardState. Like [this](https://github.com/android/snippets/blob/864fd5598518a54847d6dcdcb859677bee425d9b/compose/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/compose/snippets/state/StateOverviewSnippets.kt#L219-L231)